# How to install LXDE on CentOS 7 x64?

Tags: centos, desktop-environment, lxde

```
[root@localhost iexcept]# uname -or
3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@localhost iexcept]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
[root@localhost iexcept]# yum install lxde
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.besthosting.ua
 * extras: mirror.besthosting.ua
 * linuxtech-release: pkgrepo.linuxtech.net
 * updates: mirror.besthosting.ua
No package lxde available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@localhost iexcept]#
```

What can I do with it?
Could you please provide me with some working instructions if I have to compile it with my own hand?

Comment: First search result on google: https://www.reddit.com/r/CentOS/comments/2itlw3/lxde_for_centos_7/

Comment: those guys haven't found solution, except xfce (but it's not the same as **lxde** right? )